# Maven archetype filename pattern with underscore

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm creating a Maven archetype.  I want to generate files like `project_todo_messages.properties` with `todo` replaced by a filtered property.

I created a file `project___todo___messages.properties` and a filtered property `todo` in `archetype-metadata.xml` and `archetype.properties`.
Files without underscore are renamed, but files with underscore around the filtered property are not. Any ideas?

I use maven-archetype-plugin 2.3 and org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-packaging 2.3.

Other question : is it possible to lowercase a filtered value in a filename like it is possible in a file content with `${todo.toLowerCase()}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish both by adding required properties with default values set to the filter you want.

For the first case:

```
<requiredProperty key="messagePropertiesFileName">
    <defaultValue>project_${todo}_messages</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Name the file `__messagePropertiesFileName__.properties`.

For the second case, add yet another property:

```
<requiredProperty key="todoLowerCase">
    <defaultValue>${todo.toLowerCase()}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Use `__todoLowerCase__` in folder/file names.

Comment: i am doing this yet i am still getting the file name ${something}, the required property is not being replaced.

Comment: This happened to me in Eclipse, but when running from command line it worked. I have to see why in Eclipse doesn't work. Maybe it's running older version of maven.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet from archetype plugin source:

```
for ( Iterator<?> iterator = request.getProperties().keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); )
    {
        String key = (String) iterator.next();

        String value = request.getProperties().getProperty( key );
        ... Velocity evaluation ...
```

original property (in your case ${todo}) hasn't been processed by Velocity, so Velocity can't calculate the real value of ${todo.toLowerCase()}. 
Try to rename the properties and hope that it will appear in the right order in request.getProperties().keySet().iterator()