# How can I apply Velocity formatting to variables in filenames in a maven archetype?

Tags: maven, velocity, maven-archetype

In my `archetype-metadata.xml`, I have a property defined like:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="foo"/>
</requiredProperties>
```

I can use Velocity for manipulation of text inside files, for example:

```
#set( $foo-lower = $foo.toLowerCase() )
...
<someTag>${foo-lower}</someTag>
```

I also use variable substitution in filenames, like: `myfile__foo__.txt`

Is there a way to apply Velocity pre-processing in a way similar to the approach used inside a file, so that I could use `myfile__foo-lower__.txt`?

Perhaps a way to globally define a new variable, that will apply to all substitutions everywhere?

Comment: Did you come accross this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29647938/1743880

Comment: This works, but the solution there is not ideal, since it results in the new required property being presented to the user at generate time.  Is there any way for this implementation detail to be hidden from the user?

Comment: No, I don't think it is currently possible.

Comment: Also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266464/can-i-convert-an-artifactid-to-a-classname-prefix-in-my-maven-archetype